# How do you programmatically make UIViews which are the height of textLabels inside them? (In Swift)

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uitextview, subview

I'm trying to make UIViews which each contain different statements of text (In UITextViews). There can be a varying number of views and each statement can be different in length. I make these views using

```
let newView = DragView(heightOfView: ???, viewNumber: i, heightFromTop: currentHeightForThings)
```

In the DragView class I then access the statement using the viewNumber and put the statement in the text label in a nib file I've made.

My issue is I have nothing to put in heightOfView. The height I want is the height of the textLabel which varies depending on how many lines are in the textView for the statement. However I can't access this height because the textLabel isn't built yet.

Thanks in advance, I'm new to swift but want to learn fast so I apologise if I'm missing something obvious!

---

Heres the code I have in the class DragView

```
class DragView: UIView {

    @IBOutlet var dragView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var statementLabel: UITextView!

    var dropTarget: UIView?
    var viewNumber: Int!

    init(heightOfView: Int, viewNumber:Int, heightFromTop: Int) {
        self.viewNumber = viewNumber
        let startingPosition = CGRect(x: Int(widthCentre) - dragViewWidth / 2, y: heightFromTop, width: dragViewWidth, height: heightOfView)
        super.init(frame: startingPosition)

        NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("DragView", owner: self, options:  nil)

        self.addSubview(self.dragView)
        let movingView = MovingView(frame: startingPosition)
        self.addSubview(movingView)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}
```

Here the movingView is a subview I add over the view to move the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the `DragView`'s `sizeThatFits` method to have it return a height based on the `statementLabel`'s height. You will have to first call `sizeToFit` on the `textView` which will set the height for that view, then return a height based on that.

```
override func sizeThatFits(size: CGSize) -> CGSize {
    self.statementLabel.sizeToFit()
    return CGSize(
        width: self.frame.width, 
        height: self.statementLabel.frame.height)
}
```

Additionally, I would recommend looking into `sizeThatFits` and `layoutSubviews` if you are going to be doing programatic layout. The sizing and positioning of subviews should be taking place in `layoutSubviews` rather than `init`.

Comment: Thanks I studied the documentation for sizeToFit and this worked!